# MySQL Trigger before update - set dateformat from string

Tags: mysql, datetime, triggers

i have a site where i can update the date of a row, by clicking on the table, when i change the value and press enter its updated in the database.

what i want: in the date field. just to type mm/dd (e.g. 05-20) press enter.

then my trigger should:

```
CREATE TRIGGER before_transactions_update 
BEFORE UPDATE
ON Transactions FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
 -- variable declarations
    declare inputDate integer;


-- trigger code
-- get month and day
-- LEFT(inputDate, 2); RIGHT(inputDate, 2)
-- STR_TO_DATE('2015,MONTH(LEFT),DAY(RIGHT)','%Y,%m,%d');
   SET INSERTED.date = 2015-month-day-00-00-00;

END;
```

this is what i've "tried" or at least as far as i have come on my own. MySQL workbench stops me at the declaration of my var, it tells me i need a semi colon after declaration, which i dont seem to need

So i've been googling for hours and i've met a dead end as a newbie in MySQL so could anyone fill out the blanks or point me in the right direction,

that would be great

Answer (score 0):

You can not pass the input parameter directly into the trigger unless that input is somewhere in the `update statement`

Also you need to specify a delimiter in the trigger.

If your input values are always in the form `m-d` as  you shown in the example and the `year` is the current year then the following trigger should do the job.

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER before_transactions_update BEFORE UPDATE
ON Transactions 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   if length(new.date) = 5  then
     set new.date = concat(year(curdate()),'-',new.date);
   end if ;
END;//

delimiter ;
```

Comment: This results in 0000-00-00 00:00:00.. so i tried adding:      set new.date = concat(year,"-",(curdate()),'-',new.date,' 00:00:00'); for the proper format for a timestamp, no luck, and also, could you explain your code a little? (the if statement in particular) Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to make sure that the values for `date` is getting send properly. As I said it has to be in `m-d` format, if you are using some other format it will not work. The if statement is say you already had some data with the correct date, and say you are updating something from mysql then it might create a conflict. Or better to check the string length as `if length(new.date) = 5` meaning you are sending data as `m-d` format so add the year data into it else leave it how it is.

Comment: Also provide the update query that you will execute if possible the values of `date` that are in the update query.

Comment: UPDATE Transactions
SET date = 10-10 WHERE transaction_id =4;

this results in the above 00 00 00 00 00

Comment: Try as `UPDATE Transactions SET date = '10-10' WHERE transaction_id =4; ` and delete the trigger and re-create with the updated one. Make sure that the `date` column is having the datatype as `date or datetime or timestamp`

Comment: data truncated for column 'date' with the single quotes. 
and without single quotes, it says 1 row changed, but still plain zeroes.
And the field is a timestamp with default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Comment: For date inputs you need quotes and since you are using the update form for the date field I would suggest to use `date or datetime` and no need to have the default current_timestamp.

Comment: Well sadly, as it is i have no way of changing the datatype. and with '10-10' data is truncated, so is it fixable in any way without changing the data type?

Comment: You do not need to change the `datatype` however one thing you can do is to concat the `00:00:00` as well `concat(year(curdate()),'-',new.date,'00:00:00');` and see if this makes changes.

Comment: Still no luck.. is there any way of printing the date that it is trying to insert? to find a possible error in the format

Comment: i will return to my trigger later on... but so far, thanks a lot for your assistance.